# Getting YouTube URL for downloading video

Tags: python, video, youtube

I am writing a Python script for downloading a YouTube video. I am sending a request to a certain YouTube URL and getting it's response. Now, I want to get the URL of that video so that I can download it. All the answers I have found are outdated. Where in the response is the video URL hidden? Or there is no way to get the video URL?

```
import urllib2
import json
f = open("video.txt","w")
response = urllib2.urlopen("https://youtu.be/OulN7vTDq1I")
f.write(response.read())
```

And I got something like this in embed part of response:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOulN7vTDq1I" title="Badshah - DJ Waley Babu | feat Aastha Gill | Party Anthem Of 2015 | DJ Wale Babu">
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=xml&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOulN7vTDq1I" title="Badshah - DJ Waley Babu | feat Aastha Gill | Party Anthem Of 2015 | DJ Wale Babu">
```

Comment: It's much more complicated then that... YouTube don't use .mp4 they stream the videos directly to the "player"

Answer (score 1):

Use pyTube - lightweight, dependency-free Python library (and command-line utility) for downloading YouTube Videos.

https://github.com/nficano/pytube

Comment: I was trying to implement my own.

Comment: If you're going to suggest a library you might want to consider adding a small snippet displaying it's usage in relation to the question. Posting link-only answers will, most likely, get this answer flagged as Low Quality.